# Using IF Then to change cells to reflect page numbers

Tags: excel, vba

Before

[image: Image of spreadsheet before]

After

[image: What I'm hoping the outcome will be]

I'm trying to find a way to setup certain pages in column N based on the spreadnames of Column AC. For example any spreadname that has "EOC" in column AC should then show "EOC" in Column N. To add to that I need any spreaname in column AC that has OBC + a Number to show in column N as OB# (and that number).

The code I have so far obviously changing the specified cells but not the entire column. I thought I might be able to do a simple lrow to get it to go but that isn't going to work and then I thought about doing a loop but given the number of rows I'm worried that will take way too long to process. So I'm wondering if there isn't a better way of doing this. Any help in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

```
 Sub Pages()
  'Set Pages based on Spreadname

 Dim lrow As Long
 Dim sCellVal As String

 lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row

 sCellVal = Range("AC2").Value

 If sCellVal Like "*EOC*" Then
 Range("N2").Value = "EOC"
 End If

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will loop your logic down the entire column starting at the 2nd row (*assuming you have a header row*)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Pages()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Update!!
Dim LR As Long, i As Long

LR = ws.Range("AC" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LR
    If ws.Range("AC" & i) Like "*EOC*" Then
        ws.Range("N" & i) = "EOC"
    ElseIf Left(ws.Range("AC" & i), 3) = "OBC" Then
        ws.Range("N" & i) = "OB" & Right(ws.Range("AC" & i), 1)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help! It's greatly appreciated!